# PHP MySQL result issue when using a variable in the WHERE Clause

Tags: php, mysql, sql, mysqli

I am having a pretty weird problem with my PHP MySQL Query, I am trying to return rows that have the correct rname, rcity, and rstate values.

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM `images` WHERE rname = '" . $rname . "' AND rcity = '" . $rcity . "' AND rstate = '" . $rstate . "'";
```

When I run that query, it only returns 0 results. However after some playing around with it, If I only use rname and rstate in the WHERE Clause it returns results.

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM `images` WHERE rname = '" . $rname . "' AND rstate = '" . $rstate . "';
```

That works perfect. So when i tried just useing rcity in the WHERE Clause.

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM `images` WHERE rcity = '" . $rcity . "'";
```

0 results return. So something is wrong with the rcity portion of the query. If I hard write the value into the query instead of the $rcity variable, it pulls up results. I doubled checked to make sure $rcity was declared, it has the correct value, etc.

I also created another test table in the database to check to see if it was a problem on the db side. Which the problem still existed.

Here is the full code of the getQuery() Function

```
private function getQuery($data){
    // Takes raw data and creats image(s) query to search for listing resort...
        $listing = $data['listing'];
        $rname = $data['rname'];
        $rcity = $data['rcity'];
        $rstate = $data['rstate'];

        $query = "SELECT * FROM `test` WHERE rname = '" . $rname . "' AND rcity = '" . $rcity . "' AND rstate = '" . $rstate ."'";

        return $query;
}
```

And Here is my database class

```
class db {

        public function __construct(){
            $this->server = DB_SERVER;
            $this->user = DB_USER;
            $this->Pass = DB_PASS;
            $this->Database = DB_Database;
        }

        protected function connect(){
            return mysqli_connect($this->server, $this->user, $this->Pass, $this->Database);
        }

        public function query($sql){

            $conn = $this->connect();
            $query = $conn->query($sql);

                if($query == false) {
                    throw new Exception("Query failed:".PHP_EOL.$conn->error.PHP_EOL.$sql);
                }
                if($query->num_rows == 0) {
                    // need E_NOTICE errors enabled to see this,
                    // on screen if display_errors is on, else in PHP error log
                    trigger_error("Query returned 0 rows:".PHP_EOL.$sql);
                }
                $result = array();
                    while ($row = $query->fetch_assoc()){
                        $result[] = $row;
                    }
                return $result;
        }

    }
```

I call the query in a class __construct function like so

```
$con = new db;

    $sql = $this->getQuery($data);
    $result = $con->query($sql);
```

Comment: Can you try building the query like this: `$query = "SELECT * FROM \`test\` WHERE rname LIKE '%$rname%' AND rcity LIKE '%$rcity%' AND rstate LIKE '%$rstate%' ;";` and let me know any change? The `%` is a wildcard character and will return rows that *contain* the variable value, not match identically.

Comment: What is the value of $rstate? Have you just done a `die($rstate);` to verify you have what you think you do? If you do have a legit value for $rstate, are you sure there are matching values in the DB?

Comment: may be its an white space issue? either in DB or in requested data ?

Comment: Agreed with Abhik, that's what I was getting at. Try `echo "[$rcity]";` to see if there's any whitespace in the variable passed in.

Comment: Are you sure you can trust the $rcity var, where comes from the content ? just var_dump($rcity) and check the result.

Comment: I tried to use that query you posted and same thing, "Query returned 0 rows". I need them to match exactly to rname, rcity, rstate. 

I echoed out $rcity and it is the correct value "Las Vegas" I also echoed out the $query and copied and pasted it directly into my MySQL Client and it works perfectly. So its a problem with php not allowing rcity to use a variable as a value.

Comment: Well that sure is perplexing! I see no logic in your database class that would affect the query. And if you cut and paste the output query into MySQL client and it works, that makes no sense. Could there be additional non-unicode characters that phpmyadmin or mysql client is stripping, that PHP is not?

Comment: Not that I can tell, how could I check that? I am still having this problem and it is only caused by fcity having a variable value in the sql query... :/

Answer (score 1):

I think problem can be with syntax or mysql screening. Try to use [PDO with bindParam method](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.bindparam.php)

Answer (score -1):

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM `images` WHERE rname = '$rname' AND rcity = '$rcity' AND rstate = '$rstate'";
```

Try to implement this i.e. using variable directly between `'` (apostrophe), It should work perfect

Comment: Still coming up with the notice. "Query returned 0 rows". If i echo out the $sql, copy and paste it into my MySQL Client it works perfectly. As far as I can tell, PHP is not liking when I give rcity a variable value. If I leave rname and rstate as a variable value and hard code rcity to 'Las Vegas' (Which is what $rcity echoes) It works. But right when I give rcity a variable like rcity='$rcity' in the sql, it goes back to returning 0 rows.

Comment: What is your database data, Try to directly Using query in SQL command window in phpmyadmin.

Comment: The query works like it should when I directly use it in phpMyAdmin.